# Doorbell issues?

Tags: resistors

Not sure if this question should be posted here so if not then I’m sorry.

I’ve got a problem I’m hoping one of you might be able to help me with.

I’ve got a mechanical doorbell chime and it constantly has 1v ac going through it which is causing the solenoid to make a really annoying noise.

I need to keep that 1v as my doorbell outside needs that to run while on standby (Its one of the ring pro’s with the camera and led).

The doorbell and chime are wired up to the supplies ring transformer which is 12v/10va.

Anyway, to solve the problem I was thinking I could put a small resistor across the solenoid terminals in the chime to allow the 1v to bypass the solenoid but when the doorbell is pressed and the doorbell sends what seems to be 8v to the chime to ring it the resistor won’t allow that 8v to bypass so the door chime should get 7v and still work.

Im not sure if I’m correct in saying that’s how a resistor works.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did chime come with outdoor controller? or separate? I suspect separate.

Comment: AC or DC readings?

Comment: The proper solution would be to provide a separate conductor back to the transformer from the outside. A resistor across the solenoid might work, but you would need a value that would pass enough current  to allow the outside device to function without allowing too much through the solenoid. It is a current divider problem without the current requirement given. There is not necessarily any resistor value that will provide the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the chime is my original chime so it didn’t come with the doorbell and the readings are ac. I wouldn’t be able to bring a separate conductor back from the doorbell now but if I could would I still need the resistor in order for the chime to receive the correct voltage? I’ve ordered a 1ohm 1w resistor to try going across the solenoid but guessing that’s probably not going to work now,

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWI2Z7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The bell might buzz, but perhaps if you interpose a relay, the relay
won't.   Finding a low-voltage AC relay is possible, but a few
rectifiers and an automobile-type 12VDC relay might be easier on
the wallet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok, I think I understand how that would work. Probably a bit beyond me tbh. If I went with the low voltage ac rely do I just need to make sure it’s suitable for 12v ac or would there be anything else spec wise I need to check?

Comment: Sorry guys not really that clued up with electronics.

Comment: @Ross The relay will have some load from the bell (not much), so if there's any data on the mechanism, or a data label, you could check against that.   Mainly, though, this isn't a stressful application.   There are lots of unknowns, I'm just assuming the bell is low-voltage AC (most that I've seen are).

Comment: That’s correct. The chime is rated at 8-16v ac, and the doorbell controller requires a power source that supplies a minimum of 16 volts AC at ~15-20 volt-amps. For the doorbell to function correctly, the voltage needs to be at least 3,900mV. The transformer is 12v 10va but the reader on my meter is 18v ac.